# Identify a portlet first render phase

Tags: liferay, render, portlet

How can I know if a render phase is the first render phase of a portlet?

I want to show a list of all my organization users in Liferay and be able to filter the results by writing a name in a text field.

My problem comes when inserting a name of a user in the text field. I want to search users with that name in some of his/her attributes, and show only these users. I don't know why, all users are shown again although I store my resulting reasearch as an attribute in the actionRequest:

actionRequest.setAttribute("usersList", users);

and try to print only these users. The render phase after this action phase is not taking my attribute to render only the founded users.

So my intention is to identify somehow if my render phase is the first one, or if it comes after an action phase so that I can create a condition to print all users or to print users from my List stored in the actionRequest.setAttribute.

Thank you very much, hope you can help, btw I continue researching on my own.

Comment: can you elaborate a little on your question. May be give an example of what you want to do or the requirement.

Comment: can u post the code for action and render methods?

Answer (score 1):

Let me give little details on type of requests

1) Action Requests : These are used to provide data to server, like post, submitting forms, more processing on submitting (Data storage)

2) Render Requests : They paint your html part, here you can retrieve data from database, arrange it, butify it and store in request attribute, from presentation layer, get this and paint it.

If you want to use render request directly, Please create a render URL instead of action URL, let say, if you have submit button of form, then your action attribute of your html form should have "", this will directly call the render method and will not go to action.

Hope this helps.

--Felix

Answer (score 0):

Try using ActionResponse.setRenderParameter.
The render parameters will be there in the Render phase, you can access them with the getParameter method in the RenderRequest class.

Answer (score 0):

I have bad news, you can't pass parameters like that from action request to render request as action request only lives through the action phase. Therefore, you can't retrieve those values from render phase.

The only way (as far as I know) to pass an attribute from action to render is to use

```
actionResponse.setRenderParameter("name", "value")
```

Note the the value must be a string! So you can't pass e.g. a list of objects.

Your options are to

1) Do your actual search in render phase.
2) Put the results in session, so they are available in render phase as well.

If you go with option 1, just forget about the action phase completely and post your search form to the render phase method. That's what I do quite often in these situations.

Comment: Here is a good Liferay doc about the issue as well. http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/passing-information-from-the-action-phase-to-the-render-phase